# how to wait for several callbacks to be received

Tags: c#, events

I have such code:

```
    public void IssueOrders(List<OrderAction> actions)
    {
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            if (action is AddOrder)
            {
                uint userId = apiTransactions.PlaceOrder((action as AddOrder).order);
                Console.WriteLine("order is placing userId = " + userId);
            }
            // TODO: implement other actions
        }
        // how to wait until OnApiTransactionsDataMessageReceived for all userId is received?

        // TODO: need to update actions with received data here
    }

    private void OnApiTransactionsDataMessageReceived(object sender, DataMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataMsg = e.message;
        var userId = dataMsg.UserId;
```

`apiTransactions.PlaceOrder` is asynchronous so I receive `userId` as result but I will receive data in callback OnApiTransactionsDataMessageReceived.

So for example If I place 3 orders, i will receive 3 userId, for example `1`, `3`, and `4`. Now I need to wait until data for all these userId is received.

`userId` is always increasing if this is important. This is almost integer numbers sequence, but some numbers may be ommited due parallel execution.

**UPD** Note:

- IssueOrders can be executed parallel from different threads
- callack may be called BEFORE PlaceOrder returns

**UPD2**

Likely I need to refactor PlaceOrder code below so I can guarantee that `userId` is known before "callback" is received:

```
    public uint PlaceOrder(Order order)
    {
        Publisher pub = GetPublisher();

        SchemeDesc schemeDesc = pub.Scheme;
        MessageDesc messageDesc = schemeDesc.Messages[0]; //AddMM
        FieldDesc fieldDesc = messageDesc.Fields[3];
        Message sendMessage = pub.NewMessage(MessageKeyType.KeyName, "FutAddOrder");

        DataMessage smsg = (DataMessage)sendMessage;
        uint userId = counter.Next();
        FillDataMessageWithPlaceOrder(smsg, order, userId);

        System.Console.WriteLine("posting message dump: {0}", sendMessage);
        pub.Post(sendMessage, PublishFlag.NeedReply);
        sendMessage.Dispose();

        return userId;
    }
```

So I need to split PlaceOrder to two methods: `userId CreateOrder` and `void PostOrder`. This will guarantee that when callback is received I know `userId`.

Comment: You will need to create a class that subscribes to the event and does the accounting. But perhaps the most important question is: what does "wait" mean? Ideally the thread should block so as not to consume CPU, but can your code handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most silly and working approaches would be:

```
public void IssueOrders(List<OrderAction> actions)
{
    var userIds = new List<uint>();
    lock(theHashMap)
        theHashMap[userIds] = "blargh";

    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        if (action is AddOrder)
        {
            lock(userIds)
            {
               uint userId = apiTransactions.PlaceOrder((action as AddOrder).order);
               Console.WriteLine("order is placing userId = " + userId);

               userIds.Add(userId);
            }
        }

        // TODO: implement other actions
    }

    // waiting:
    do
    {
       lock(userIds)
          if(userIds.Count == 0)
             break;

       Thread.Sleep(???); // adjust the time depending on how long you wait for a callback on average

    }while(true);

    lock(theHashMap)
        theHashMap.Remove(userIds);

    // now you have the guarantee that all were received
}

private Dictionary<List<uint>, string> theHashMap = new Dictionary<List<uint>,string>();

private void OnApiTransactionsDataMessageReceived(object sender, DataMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataMsg = e.message;
    var userId = dataMsg.UserId;

    // do some other things

    lock(theHashMap)
        foreach(var list in theHashMap.Keys)
           lock(list)
              if(list.Remove(userId))
                 break;
}
```

but, this is quite crude approach.. Its hard to suggest anything more unless you explain what do yo umean by wait - as Jon asked in the comments. For example, you may might want to leave the `IssueOrders`, wait anywhere, and just be sure that the some extra job is done when all have arrived? Or maybe you cannot leave the `IssueOrders` unless all are received? etc..

Edit: please note that near ADD, the lock must be **before** PlaceOrder, or else, when the callback arrive hyper-fast, the callback may attempt to remove the ID before it is added. Also, note that this implementation is very naiive: the callback must search and lock through all the lists at each time. With a few additional dictionary/maps/indexes, it may be optimized much, but I did not do that here for readability.

Comment: Florian's approach is better when you have to wait long time for the callback to arrive (less spinning), but mine is better when you have to wait for thousands of callbacks (less resources taken)

Comment: well I was thinking to block in IssueOrders. once data is received I also need to UPDATE corresponding actions! so caller passes to IssueOrders the list of actions. IssueOrders executes, blocks, collects, updates, and returns

Comment: You've said in other comments that your `IssueOrders` may be called from different threads - this is a **VERY** important information. You should have included it in the original question! This means that neither Florian, nor my original suggestion will work, as the shared themap/m_Events would get spoiled when another caller enters the method while the first one still waits. You will have to push the grouping one more level down, see my updated code above. Note that if you modify Florian's code similarly - it would also be valid.

Comment: Also, check the comments about threading issues and locks I've added at the end of the post. Anyways, I too strongly suggest that you try refactoring the API to use more Reactive, TPL, or other async .Net API. While as I shown it is not _strictly necessary_, and you can do it with plain .net/c# - using them will greatly improve readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: also there is another problem. i actually can receive callback BEFORE PlaceOrder returns, and I should process this correctly as well.

Comment: well this is rare situation. occurs once per 10000000 of calls, but it occurs and I can't do anything with that because this is how underling library works. this just means that co-location stock exchange access is so fast that network sometimes works faster than CPU. of course when CPU lags for a moment :)

Comment: The fact that you get a callback before the `PlaceOrder` return is actually a bug in the architecture. Or maybe not a bug, but at least "a serious issue". Your peer system should ensure that it never notifies you about completion before it finishes processing the request. The issue may be on your side, if the remote call is quick and it is just the `PlaceOrder` that does some heavy waiting afterwards before returning. Currently, your code here does not learn what is the UserID before the method returns - thus, when the callback arrives, your code **does not know what to wait for** yet.

Comment: code should wait until userId which was received from callback will be associated with one of the actions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16289/discussion-between-quetzalcoatl-and-javapowered)

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the [ForkJoin](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc3) method in the Reactive Framework. It will block until multiple async calls have completed.

**Edit:** It seems that ForkJoin() was only ever included in an experimental release of Rx. Here's a [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/3cfccb74-9ce3-47dc-94fd-cf60270c1ed5/) of what you want based on Merge().

Answer (score 0):

In case you are able to change the API, consider to use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), your code will get much easier with that.

Otherwise [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) might help you:

```
    private Dictionary<int, AutoResetEvent> m_Events = new ...;

    public void IssueOrders(List<OrderAction> actions)
    {
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            if (action is AddOrder)
            {
                uint userId = apiTransactions.PlaceOrder((action as AddOrder).order);
                // Attention: Race condition if PlaceOrder finishes                                         
                // before the MRE is created and added to the dictionary!
                m_Events[userId] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                Console.WriteLine("order is placing userId = " + userId);
            }
            // TODO: implement other actions
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(m_Events.Values);

        // TODO: Dispose the created MREs
    }

    private void OnApiTransactionsDataMessageReceived(object sender, DataMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataMsg = e.message;
        var userId = dataMsg.UserId;

        m_Events[userId].Set();
    }
```

Comment: My answer is quite similar, but uses manual polling instead of events.  Florian's approach is better when you have to wait long time for the callback to arrive (less spinning), but mine is better when you have to wait for thousands of callbacks (less resources)

Comment: your approach with AutoResetEvent doesn't work because several reasons: IssueOrders may be executed parallel from different threads, `WaitHandle.WaitAll(m_Events.Values);` will wait for all items in array, but I only need for subset of array with certain userIds. What do you suggest to use from TPL?

Comment: Well, of course this is no complete solution but only a direction you might go for.

Comment: Have a look at the `Task` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx), it provides a property `Result` which blocks until the result is available. In your case just change `apiTransactions.PlaceOrder` to return e.g. a `Task<PlaceOrderResult>`  which contains the data you produce asynchronously.

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher it's very interesting to use Task. if you can link complete example it would be very helpful